# Вызвать событие нажатия кнопок Sum и Sub элемента <input type = "number">

Tags: html, css, jquery

Мне нужно настроить таргетинг на теги `<p>` для кнопок Sub и Sum элемента `<input type="number">`. Если я нажму на `#selCountSub`, число должно увеличиться, а если на `#selCountSum`, то число уменьшится соответственно.

Я могу написать простую логику, которая будет делать то, что я хочу. Но я хочу знать, есть ли способ запустить внутренние кнопки элемента, нажав на теги `<p>`.

Я пробовал разные способы, но ни один из них не работает. Спасибо за отзывчивость и потраченное время.

```js
jQuery("#selCountSub").on("click", function () {
    jQuery("input[type=number]").trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown change"));
});

jQuery("#selCountSum").on("click", function () {
    jQuery("input[type=number]").trigger(jQuery.Event("keyup change"));
});
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="selCountSub">-</p>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" />
<p id="selCountSum">+</p>
```

Comment: а что Ваш скрипт сейчас делает?

Comment: @humster_spb, Сейчас он ничего не делает. Это неудачная и глупая попытка вызвать `keydown` и `keyup`.

Comment: ну то есть надо, чтобы просто value в инпуте увеличивался и уменьшался, да?

Comment: @humster_spb, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как-то так можно, например:

```js
let count = $('input').val();
$('p').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'selCountSub' && count > 1) {
    count--;
  }
  else if($(this).attr('id') == 'selCountSum') {
    count++;
  }
  $('input').val(count);
})
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="selCountSub">-</p>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" />
<p id="selCountSum">+</p>
```

Comment: Не работает атрибут `min="1"`

Comment: @UModeL, а должен? ))

Comment: в дубликате отлично работает.

Comment: @UModeL, ну, я добавил проверку на единицу. В условиях автор просто не написал, что надо, а на атрибут я не обратил внимания. Сути ответа это не меняет.